# Deriving Maxwell equations in Newman-Penrose formalism

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, spinors

I am trying to derive the NP formalism version of Maxwell's, following [Chandrasekhar's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198503709) and using the [xAct](http://www.xact.es/) package for Mathematica.

First I have the usual Maxwell equation

$$
 \nabla_a F^{ab}= J^{b}
$$

Rewriting this in terms of partial and derivative Christoffel symbols
[image]

Where $D$ denotes the partial derivative, if I express this expression on a null tetrad with after identifying the Ricci rotational coefficients and using the standard directional derivatives I get
[image]

Where greek symbols denote the standard NP, blue indices denote components with respect to the tetrad basis.
Now if we look and the definition of Chandrasekhar

$$
\phi_0 = F^{ij}l_i n_j = F^{12}
$$

$$
\phi_1 = \frac{1}{2} F^{ij}(l_i n_j + \tilde{m}^i m^j) = F^{12} + F^{43}
$$

$$
\phi_2 = F^{ij}\tilde{m}^i n^j = F^{42}
$$

we see that we can rewrite most of the final equation in terms of the scalars $\phi_i, i = 0,1,2$ but that there is also the term which includes $F^{14}$ which I cannot get rid of, can any of you see where am I making the mistake? Am I approaching the problem wrong?

Comment: Note that I also tried using the other set of Maxwell equations, which didn't help me either.

Comment: For the calculations of the scalars $\phi_i$, you can refer to chapter 5 from spinors and space-time volume -I by Penrose &Rindler

Comment: I suggest you post this question also in the xAct group (https://groups.google.com/g/xAct?hl=en) where you can post your notebook and  might get a specific xAct-help

Comment: I will try, thank you